# Most efficient way to migrate from timestamp to from-to columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given a table `Orders` with columns:

```
id | revision | insertedAt           
1           0   2016-01-01 00:00.000
1           1   2016-01-01 02:00.000
2           0   2016-01-01 02:00.000
```

Where the id, revision combination is unique.

How can I best migrate to this:

```
id | revision | applyFrom           | applyTo
1           0   2016-01-01 00:00.000   2016-01-01 01:99.999
1           1   2016-01-01 02:00.000   9999-31-12 00:00.000
2           0   2016-01-01 02:00.000   9999-31-12 00:00.000
```

I've tried iterating over a `CURSOR` and updating as I go along.

```
UPDATE orders SET applyFrom = @newApplyFrom, applyTo = @newApplyTo
WHERE id = @id AND revision = @revision;
```

But with 226 million rows, estimated runtime is somewhere near 60 hours, even hitting the index.

Is there a faster way of achieving the same result? I can add indices as needed. Currently, there is a clustered index on (id, revision).

Comment: Are `revision` values guaranteed to always start at 0 and contain no gaps?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: There can be gaps due to loss of connectivity to the provider of the data. In which case, we should pretend the missing revision never happened. Likewise, they are not guaranteed to start at 0, but will 99% of the time.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen you could use an update statement using LEAD to check if the next id is the same, and i so use LEAD again to grab the next value, else go 9999. Assuming you can order by id, revision, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version including `LEAD` and a self join. Not sure about the performance on large data sets, but I've included batching just in case.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        revision, 
        insertedAt, 
        applyFrom,
        applyTo,
        LEAD(insertedAt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, revision) AS newApplyTo
    FROM orders
)
UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) o SET
     applyFrom = o.insertedAt,
     applyTo = ISNULL(DATEADD(s, -1, o.newApplyTo), '9999-12-31')  
FROM cte o
WHERE 
    o.applyFrom IS NULL AND 
    o.applyTo IS NULL;
```

The dataset I've used (with results) is:

```
Id          revision    insertedAt                  applyFrom                   applyTo
----------- ----------- --------------------------- --------------------------- ---------------------------
1           0           2016-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 2016-01-01 01:59:59.0000000
1           1           2016-01-01 02:00:00.0000000 2016-01-01 02:00:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000
2           0           2016-01-01 02:00:00.0000000 2016-01-01 02:00:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000
3           0           2016-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 2016-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 2016-10-31 23:59:59.0000000
3           1           2016-11-01 00:00:00.0000000 2016-11-01 00:00:00.0000000 2016-11-30 23:59:59.0000000
3           2           2016-12-01 00:00:00.0000000 2016-12-01 00:00:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: I can unfortunately only accept one answer, but I applied a little of the accepted answer and a little of this to arrive where I wanted. I did it without the join, so I don't know it impacts performance. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I don't even need the join. Updated for posterity, and glad you fixed your issue!

Comment: Accepted this instead as it is more complete. Future readers should note however, that the batching should be on the ID column, not using TOP. (Otherwise you might cut off mid-order)

Comment: @TroelsLarsen Even if it does stop in the middle, it should resume cleanly

Comment: Oh, so LEAD/LAG will work even when the next or previous is not in the result set? Nice to know.

Comment: Yep, Window functions care about their partition and their specific order by clauses. Other rows should not matter.

Comment: Still need some testing to ensure data is migrated correctly, but time went from 60+ hours to roughly 200 minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can update like below: I am using lead and showing with select

```
;with cte as (
select *, lead(insertedAt,1,'9999-12-31 00:00.000') over(order by id) migdate from Orders
)
select *, case when insertedAt = migdate then '9999-12-31 00:00.000' else DATEADD(S, -1, migdate) end as applyto  from cte
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution except that with a 226M row table, it would be best to perform the operation in batches by `id` range as to limit log space requirements.

Comment: For 226mil if you have clustered index key your update will be faster, Check you can do offline update, if that is possible then you can check whether you have associated other indexes in that table, you can drop all other indexes during this update except Clustered Index and continue the update. Also check for any indexed view associated to that table, in that case we might require to drop and recreate that as well

Comment: This seems quite reasonable. I'll give it a go (there are some more difficulties left out of the question) and wrap it in batches, then come back and accept the answer (and post the new runtime).

Comment: Unless I missed somethign in my conversion, this appears to 'roll over' regardless of id and revision. I'll try adding a clause so that it will set `applyTo` to the max date if the id changes for the next row.

Comment: Thanks. I had to make som adjustments to avoid the rollover (I used a CASE WHEN in my update statement). But 1M rows now execute in 16 seconds rather than 16 minutes!